# Building GLFW on Windows/Code Blocks

Tags: c++, opengl, mingw, glfw

I have generated the cmake folder/code blocks project, but I can't get the actual libraries to build. The examples built fine, but nothing else does. I checked the Code Blocks page (outdated, version 2.5 of GLFW - had a .bat installer) and the GLFW page (Just says to "Go ahead and compile ... as you would with any other project.") but I can't work it out. It just doesn't seem to create any libs.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find the right file after going thru all the folders, it was generated to /src/libglfw3.a, not the folder I specified in cmake :/

Comment: Did you [hit "Configure" a second time after setting the directory](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30472367/44729)?

Comment: Yeah I did, I checked the makefiles to see if I could figure out why it wasn't working right as well and I couldnt see anything. I'd guess it's just a glitch with my install of codeblocks.